# Calculate Total, New and Lost Subscription based on Month

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join, group-by

We have a table called "subscriptions" that stores information about salon subscriptions. The table has the following columns:

```
subscriptions

id, start_date, end_date, subscription_plan_id, salon_id
```

We want to write a query that provides the following information for each month:

- Date
- Total number of subscriptions (Running Total)
- Number of new subscriptions
- Number of lost subscriptions
- Total number of subscriptions for each subscription plan (standard, grow, basic, and free)
- Number of new subscriptions for each subscription plan (standard, grow, basic, and free)
- Number of lost subscriptions for each subscription plan (standard, grow, basic, and free)

The `total` values should represent the cumulative count overall, excluding lost subscriptions for each month. The `new` and `lost` values should be specific to each month.

I got the result I wanted but using the queries below

```
SELECT Date.date,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 4
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_standard_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 3
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_grow_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 2
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_basic_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 1
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_free_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 4
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_standard_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 3
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_grow_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 2
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_basic_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 1
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_free_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 4
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_standard_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 3
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_grow_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 2
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_basic_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 1
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_free_subs
        
FROM(
     SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(start_date),'-', LPAD(MONTH(start_date), 2, '0')) AS date FROM subscriptions
     UNION 
     SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(start_date),'-', LPAD(MONTH(start_date), 2, '0')) AS date FROM subscriptions
) AS Date
CROSS JOIN subscriptions AS s
WHERE Date.date <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m') 
GROUP BY Date. date
ORDER BY Date.date DESC;
```

I am looking for a more efficient and streamlined approach to achieve the same result.

Thanks For Help In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Date.date,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 4
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_standard_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 3
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_grow_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 2
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_basic_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 1
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS total_free_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 4
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_standard_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 3
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_grow_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 2
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_basic_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 1
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS new_free_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 4
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_standard_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 3
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_grow_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 2
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_basic_subs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Date.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                 AND s.subscription_plan_id = 1
                  THEN s.salon_id
                  END) AS lost_free_subs
        
FROM(
     SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(start_date),'-', LPAD(MONTH(start_date), 2, '0')) AS date FROM subscriptions
     UNION 
     SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(start_date),'-', LPAD(MONTH(start_date), 2, '0')) AS date FROM subscriptions
) AS Date
CROSS JOIN subscriptions AS s
WHERE Date.date <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m') 
GROUP BY Date. date
ORDER BY Date.date DESC;
```

This is the best possible we were able to achieve thanks to @lemons help

I am accepting this as a answer if we get any better answer in future i'll update it!

Answer (score 2):

You could try following these steps:

- replace the `INNER JOIN` with a `CROSS JOIN`
- recreate the partitions with a `CASE` expression
- apply conditional aggregation

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CONCAT(MONTH_YEAR.Y,'-', LPAD(MONTH_YEAR.m, 2, '0')) AS date,
           CASE WHEN CONCAT(MONTH_YEAR.Y,'-', LPAD(MONTH_YEAR.m, 2, '0')) <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m') 
                THEN CASE WHEN CONCAT(MONTH_YEAR.Y,'-', LPAD(MONTH_YEAR.m, 2, '0')) 
                               BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_date, '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(s.end_date, '%Y-%m') 
                          THEN 1
                          WHEN DATE_FORMAT(new.start_date, '%Y-%m') = CONCAT(MONTH_YEAR.Y,'-', LPAD(MONTH_YEAR.m, 2, '0'))
                          THEN 2
                     END
                WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(lost.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m') = CONCAT(Y, '-', LPAD(m, 2, '0'))
                 AND CONCAT(Y, '-', LPAD(m, 2, '0')) <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m')
                THEN 3
           END AS parts,
           s_subscription_plan_id
    FROM (SELECT MONTH(start_date) AS m, YEAR(start_date) AS Y FROM subscriptions
          UNION 
          SELECT MONTH(end_date)   AS m, YEAR(end_date)   AS Y FROM subscriptions) AS MONTH_YEAR
    CROSS JOIN subscriptions AS s
)
SELECT date,
       SUM(parts = 1) AS total_subscriptions,
       SUM(parts = 2) AS new_subscriptions,
       SUM(parts = 3) AS lost_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 1 AND subscription_plan_id = 4) AS total_standard_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 1 AND subscription_plan_id = 3) AS total_grow_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 1 AND subscription_plan_id = 2) AS total_basic_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 1 AND subscription_plan_id = 1) AS total_free_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 2 AND subscription_plan_id = 4) AS new_standard_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 2 AND subscription_plan_id = 3) AS new_grow_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 2 AND subscription_plan_id = 2) AS new_basic_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 2 AND subscription_plan_id = 1) AS new_free_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 3 AND subscription_plan_id = 4) AS lost_standard_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 3 AND subscription_plan_id = 3) AS lost_grow_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 3 AND subscription_plan_id = 2) AS lost_basic_subscription,
       SUM(parts = 3 AND subscription_plan_id = 1) AS lost_free_subscription
FROM cte
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: This looks good i tried working with this but it only works for total_subscriptions, new_subscriptions, and lost_subscription, but I also want those totals based on the subscription as above like total_standard, new_standard, lost_standard

i thought of using the same condition with subscription_plan_id as another and condition but that seems far fetched and to repetitive

Comment: Check the updated answer, it'll avoid repetitions better than the previous one.

Comment: It's very likely that there's no better way of how you're already doing it. Of course I couldn't know that you could remove the conditions as we don't know from our side your environment and nature of your data. You could consider adding a new answer and accepting it. Glad this answer was helpful to you.